# When spliting MP4s with ffmpeg how do I include metadata?

Tags: linux, fedora, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I have a few MP4s that i want to upload to my flickr account but they have a maximum size of 500mb as mine is only about 550 i was planing to simply split them in half then upload them, but i want to make sure all the meta data is included but it does not seem to be.
I have tried each of the following with no luck, (at the end of this post i have the original and the new ffprobe outputs):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:04:19.35 -i SANY0069.MP4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map_metadata 0:0 SANY0069A.MP4

ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:04:19.35 -i SANY0069.MP4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map_meta_data SANY0069.MP4:SANY0069A.MP4 SANY0069A.MP4
```

with the this one I manually produced the individual meta tags that i took from this command

```
ffmpeg -i SANY0069A.MP4 -f ffmetadata meta.txt
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:04:19.35 -i SANY0069.MP4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -metadata major_brand="mp42" -metadata minor_version="1" -metadata compatible_brands="mp42avc1" -metadata creation_time="2012-09-29 09:05:50" -metadata comment="SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9" -metadata comment-eng="SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9" SANY0069A.MP4
```

using the output of the former command i also tried this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:04:19.35 -i SANY0069.MP4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -f ffmetadata -i meta.txt SANY0069A.MP4
```

Output:
sample output from my first command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.00 -t 00:04:19.35 -i SANY0069.MP4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy -map_metadata 0:0 SANY0069A.MP4
ffmpeg version 0.8.12, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2012 09:57:38 with gcc 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  8. 0 / 53.  8. 0
  libavformat  53.  5. 0 / 53.  5. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SANY0069.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    comment         : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
    comment-eng     : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
  Duration: 00:08:38.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9142 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9007 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
File 'SANY0069A.MP4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'SANY0069A.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    comment         : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
    comment-eng     : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
    encoder         : Lavf53.5.0
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: libx264, yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 9007 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 7773 fps=4644 q=-1.0 Lsize=  289607kB time=00:04:19.35 bitrate=9147.4kbits/s    
video:285416kB audio:4033kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.054571%
```

and finaly, when i compare the ffprobe of the original and the first split part i get the 2 following outputs:
original

```
ffprobe version 0.8.12, Copyright (c) 2007-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2012 09:57:38 with gcc 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  8. 0 / 53.  8. 0
  libavformat  53.  5. 0 / 53.  5. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SANY0069.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    comment         : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
    comment-eng     : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
  Duration: 00:08:38.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9142 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9007 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-09-29 09:05:50
```

Split

```
ffprobe version 0.8.12, Copyright (c) 2007-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 13 2012 09:57:38 with gcc 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  8. 0 / 53.  8. 0
  libavformat  53.  5. 0 / 53.  5. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'SANY0069A.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.5.0
    comment         : SANYO DIGITAL CAMERA CA9
  Duration: 00:04:19.37, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9146 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 9015 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 127 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

I know this is incredibly long but its actually a quite simple question. I thought it would be best to provide as much detail as possible.

any advice here would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Long, detailed questions are much better than the contrary, and it is good not to have to ask for the ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Yeah i thought so, Im not exactly a linux noob so i figured this is the information that anyone who could actually help would need.

Comment: I just looked at this briefly, but I believe all but `creation_time` (unless it is omitted) and `comment` are automatically set. The behaviour of `creation_time` seems to vary between `0.8.12` and current ffmpeg from Git; it does not appear to add/copy this unless I include it. I did not refer to the code, but not copying `creation_time` when copying streams may or may not be considered a bug depending on who you ask.

Comment: I think the way it is behaving on my system would be considered a bug by all, if it is not copying the creation time from the original video then should it not set the creation time to the present? That is, instead of 1/1/1970 (the epoch?)

Also, should not the major_brand, minor_version and compatible_brands be the same if i used the "copy" codec? likewise with the encoder being set?

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg should carry over metadata automatically (so try it without `-map_metadata` and see if that works), but if it doesn't you should try using `-map_metadata 0` rather than `-map_metadata 0:0` - the `:0` there refers to the first data stream (probably the video), and ffmpeg might be trying to copy over only the stream-specific metadata, rather than that of the whole file.